# code flow of slurm gpu allocation

Tags: cluster-computing, gpu, slurm

Does any one know code flow how GPUs are allocated in SLURM?
I have gone through and found that CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable is not updated any where in code. So how actually it is done in code?

My goal is to add new hardware support using environment variable for allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the gpu gres plugin. There is where the code modifies the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable. The file path is:

```
src/plugins/gres/gpu/gres_gpu.c
```

Comment: I had seen gres_gpu.c file and also kept prints in this file but program flow is not reaching till here even if I have requested gpu devices. But if I run command "srun env" then it is showing that CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1.  So I wants to see where actually CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is getting updated. And one more thing which data structures holds information about available cpus and gpus and how much of them are occupied?